# Video Too Long to Send -- But it isn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am allowing the capture of live video in my app of which I set a maximum duration of 30 seconds.  When 30 seconds is reached the app correctly stops recording and gives a message about the max being reached.  All is good.  However, at the bottom it shows a message that says "video Too Long to Send.. Please select a smaller clip from this video".  Of course this isn't true and the video is sent just fine.  This message is very confusing to the user (given it is incorrect) and again I am already programmatically controlling video length.  This is live video and not something the user has selected from an existing library.  Why is this message showing and is there a way to get rid of it?

```
-(void)imageFromCamera:(NSString *)mediaType
{
    self.mediaPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"camera"] || [mediaType isEqualToString:@"video"]) self.mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    else self.mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"video"])
    {
        self.mediaPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        [self.mediaPicker setVideoMaximumDuration:30.0f];
    }

    self.mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    self.mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:self.mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I've made an interesting discovery with this.  The code: self.mediaPicker.allowsEditing = YES; is causing the message to appear.  If I remove this (effectively setting it to the default NO) I don't get this message.  There is nothing in the docs that would explain this.